# Significance Test Time Series Data Python

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, python

As a Business Analyst I may not be as experienced in performing complex statistical tests and this is the reason I am asking for your advice.

I have this sales data whose dates I have clustered into two groups, that is dates before price changes, dates after price changes (balanced, 45 days each).

Despite knowing trends for this kpi (rpss) are positive, and also having checked previous year's seasonality, I would like to go further and assess wether this slight increase in rpss is significant or not statistically speaking.

For that I have run the test whose Python Jupyter Notebook you will find on the link provided. I have gone for a resampling method which shows 0%, that is, the sampling distribution of this data difference ran 1000 times, is ALWAYS below the observed difference (0.50), and therefore this observed difference would be statistically significant.

I am very surprised I am getting this equivalent to a p value of 0. And I would like to know if this method is indeed applicable to this problem due to its time-series nature. Otherwise I would greatly appreciate if somebody could advise what methodology is best suited for this sort of analysis.

Thanks so much in advance,

Francisco

[significance test and dataset](https://github.com/fjcorbalan/timeseries_significancetest_python_test)